# ag-Grid show column filter and sort buttons without hover

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm using Angular and have an ag-grid-angular component with **column filter and sorting**. As you can see in the first example of [this documentation page](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/), **the user has to hover over them to see them**. This can also be seen in this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zQpVv2CZ2aYJzneMgaUQ?p=preview).

We are anticipating issues where new users won't be aware of how to use those features so **we want to have them always appear without hovering.** I've tried changing various things in ag-theme-material.css (which is the theme we're using) but to no avail. I tried changing things such as `ag-column-drop-cell-button` and others that I might suspect is the class that dictates the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come to find out that there is a specific property of ag-grid-angular for this. You simply need to set supressMenuHide to true.

```
  <ag-grid-angular
   ...
   [suppressMenuHide]="true">
  </ag-grid-angular>
```